# how to find a complete line of rows of 2d array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

how to get the number of rows which does not contains 0 ?

this try returns just the number of colums but i need the rows :

```
var items = [
      [1, 0,1],
      [3, 3,3],
      [5, 6,5]
    ];
    let result=[]
    function h(list){
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i ++){
      for(let j = 0; j < list.length; j ++)
    {
      if(list[i][j]!= 0)
    result.push(j)

    }
    return result;
    }

    }
    console.log(h(items))
```

the result should be [1,2] number of rows

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What troubles do you face wit this?

Comment: Row 1 (index 0) contains three zeros???

Comment: i updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple version:

```js
const h = items => items
  .map ( (_, i) => i )
  .filter ( i => ! items [i] .some (x => x == 0) )

var items = [ [1, 0, 1], [3, 3, 3], [5, 6, 5] ];

console .log (
  h (items)
)
```

The call to `map` turns the outer list into a list of indices.

Then `filter` is called using `some` to determine if any of the elements in the row at that index has value 0.

If you wanted the actual rows rather than their indices, then it would be simpler: `const h = items => items .filter (row => ! row .some (x => x == 0))`.

### Update

From a comment below:

> could you please simplify the syntax ? :(

Well no, not really.  This is already pretty simple.  We probably should fix something.  We're abusing `map` here.  It would be better to depend on a `range` function such as this:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => Array .from ( {length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i )
```

The idea here is that `range(3, 10)` would yield `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` (all integers starting with `lo` up to but not including `hi`.

And then we could use it like this:

```js
const h = (items) => 
  range (0, items.length)
  .filter ( i => ! items [i] .some (x => x == 0) )
```

This does not make anything more simple, only rearranges the complexity.  However, that *is* worth doing, and this is a better version.

We could also change the function we pass to `filter`.  Instead of

```js
  .filter ( i => ! items [i] .some (x => x == 0) )
```

we could easily write:

```js
  .filter ( i => items [i] .every (x => x != 0) )
```

It might be slightly easier to notice the `not-equal` sign than the stand-alone `not` one.  This is a simple matter of taste, not fundamental.  Each is equally simple.

We probably can't make this much more simple, at least not in Javascript.  I'm afraid what you're asking is for it to be more familiar to you.  Rich Hickey's classic talk [Simple Made Easy](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/) explains that complexity is about weaving together separate concerns.  Of course simplicity is the opposite, but we often confuse this with "easy".  That is a very distinct notion, one that is much more subjective, and not a good measure for software.

I can show several steps of changes that might make this more familiar to some people.  This is meant to demonstrate why you *shouldn't* do this, why you should choose simplicity over easiness.  So please don't take these as actual suggestion.

#### Using function expressions

A first pass would be simply to replace those new-fangled arrow functions with old-school function expressions

```js
const h = function (items) {
  return items.map (function (item, index) {
    return index;
  })
  .filter (function (index) {
    return ! items [index] .some (function(value) {
      return value == 0;
    })
  })
}
```

This version adds the `function` and `return` keyword, as well as changing the single-expression bodies to `{` `/*...*/` `}`.  It adds a lot of visual clutter without in any way decreasing the complexity.

But don't worry, we can easily make this worse.

Note that the outer shell of the function is still a single expression, structures as `(input).map(someFunction).filter(anotherFunction)`.  We've left us no place to easily add debugging statement.  Moreover, even if we did have such a plece, we still have no named intermediate variables to log.

Let's fix that, shall we?

#### Naming intermediate values

This version allows us to add an all-important `console.log` statement half-way through our processing:

```js
const h = function (items) {
  const indices = items .map (function (item, index) {
    return index;
  });
  // console.log(`Indices found`, indices);
  const noZeroesIndices = indices .filter (function (index) {
    return ! items [index] .some (function(value) {
      return value == 0;
    });
  })
  return noZeroesIndices;
}
```

We are definitely moving away from simplicity here.  We've just introduced a new technique to our code-base: *variable assignment*.

#### Moving to a single loop

But we're not done yet.  We also need to think hard about potential performance problems.  Our technique involves looping over the rows twice, once to find the indices, and then to use them.  If this ran over tens of millions of rows, it might take a few milliseconds longer than if we did these steps at once. Clearly there is some inefficiency here that should be rooted out immediately.<sup>1</sup>

Meanwhile, the guy down the hall told us that `.map` and `.filter` are less efficient than plain `for` loops.  It must be true for `.some` as well. So while we're replacing that additional iteration, we can move to `for` loops.  That will mean introducing some additional variables.  But it's all in a good cause.  So here it is in all its ... um, beauty:

```js
const h = function (items) {
    const noZeroesIndices = [];
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < items.length; rowIndex++) {
        const row = items[rowIndex]
        let anyZeros = false
        for (let index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {
            if (row[index] === 0) {
                anyZeros = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!anyZeros) {
            noZeroesIndices.push(rowIndex)
        }
    }
    return noZeroesIndices;
}
```

#### Conclusion

Please note that although this involved a lot of sarcasm, it wasn't directed at anyone individually.  I do a lot of code reviews in my day job, and while I have no problems with those who don't know more advanced techniques, I have too often seen a resistance to learning them.  The request above reminded me of one particular junior developer who took code reviews as the time to resist any advances in his skills.  It took a long time, and too many arguments, but recently, three years after he was under my supervision, he approached me to thank me for a patience I certainly hadn't felt at the time.  He told me that a focus on simplicity he'd learned from me had helped his skills and his career immeasurably.  So I'm going to keep pushing this lesson.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is meant to be very facetious.  Please don't optimize performance by adding complexity to your code unless you've profiled and can demonstrate that this particular section is one of the actual bottlenecks causing unacceptable execution speeds.

Comment: could you please simplify the syntax ? :(

Comment: @Alex: updated with a long rant.  Please don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var items = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [5, 6, 5]
];

function h(list) {
    let result = []; // result variable should be in the function
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[i][j] !== 0)
                result.push(list[i][j]) // push value not key
        }
        // here is not place for return
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(h(items));
```

Comment: what i need list of [1,2] number of rows

Comment: This is not what the OP was looking for, but do note that modern `Array.prototype` functions make writing code to do what this does this much easier: `const h = items => items.flatMap(row => row.filter(x => x != 0))`